# Memory limit of 256 mb exceeded? Why?

Tags: c++11

I was solving this problem on codeforces [here](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/828/A), the code displays right answer but it exceeds the memory limit on the site. I can't figure out why. Also tried to use vectors but it doesn't work.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,a,b,c,deny=0;
    int groups[n];
    scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&a,&b);


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>groups[i];
        }

    int two_one=b*2;
    //two kinds of tables:one seater,2 seater
    //find no of ppl denied service
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(groups[j]==1 and a!=0){
            a-=1;   
        }
        else if(groups[j]==1 and a==0){
            two_one-=1;
            b-=1;


        }
        else if(groups[j]==1 and a==0 and two_one==0){
            deny+=1;
        }
        else if(groups[j]==2 and b!=0){
            b-=1;
        }
        else if(groups[j]==2 and b==0){
            deny+=2;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",deny);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, you should compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Then you'll get a useful warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to allocate an array before reading its size:

```
int n,a,b,c,deny=0; // <------ Unknown n value
int groups[n]; // <----- Allocation of array of n: undefined behavior
scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&a,&b); // <------ Reading 'groups' size
```

Just swap the last two lines.

Edit: according to the C++ standard, you should be using vectors:

```
int n,a,b,c,deny=0;
scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&a,&b);
std::vector<int> groups(n);
```

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't have variable length arrays. I'd strongly recommend using `std::vector` here instead.

Comment: @templatetypedef Sorry, you are right. Now it is fixed.